# Using ionicons in a rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ionicons

I have a rails app I'd like to use [these](https://github.com/driftyco/ionicons) in. Following the instructions, I ensured the font path in .css was assets/fonts/ionicons... but it doesn't seem to be working. Anyone ever use these before?

Comment: Hey, I am one of the creators of Ionicons. What exactly isn't working? Can you add more info?

Answer (score 7):

If anyone else has trouble to use ionicons in your rails projects, I suggest to use the gem **font-ionicons-rails** that I built.

It's very simple to use, as below:

#### Installation:

Add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem "font-ionicons-rails"
```

#### Usage:

In your application.css, include the css file:

```
/*
 *= require ionicons
 */
```

#### Sass Support

If you prefer SCSS, add this to your application.css.scss file:

```
@import "ionicons";
```

If you use the Sass indented syntax, add this to your application.css.sass file:

```
@import ionicons
```

Then restart your webserver if it was previously running.

That's all. Now you are ready to use ionicons in your project using the tag `i` or using the gem helper to improve use.

#### Helpers

```
ion_icon "camera"
# => <i class="ion-camera"></i>

ion_icon "camera", text: "Take a photo"
# => <i class="ion-camera"></i> Take a photo

ion_icon "chevron-right", text: "Get started", right: true
# => Get started <i class="ion-chevron-right"></i>

content_tag(:li, ion_icon("checkmark-round", text: "Bulleted list item"))
# => <li><i class="ion-checkmark-round"></i> Bulleted list item</li>
```

It's pretty ease now, yay.

Answer (score 4):

These are the steps I usually take:

1. Add the following to `config/application.rb`

   ```
   config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
   ```
2. Make the directory `app/assets/fonts` and copy the font files to that directory.
3. Copy `ionicons.css` to `app/assets/stylesheets`
4. Edit `ionicons.css` file and update the `url()` calls to work with the asset pipeline:

   ```
   src: font-url("ionicons.eot?v=1.3.0");
   src: font-url("ionicons.eot?v=1.3.0#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
        font-url("ionicons.ttf?v=1.3.0") format("truetype"),
        font-url("ionicons.woff?v=1.3.0") format("woff"),
        font-url("ionicons.svg?v=1.3.0#Ionicons") format("svg");
   ```

Restart webrick/thin/whatever and you should be good. :)

Comment: I don't think this is worth posting as a new answer, but if you change 'app' to 'vendor' above, you can keep this separated from your code which is especially nice when projects get large. There is also a gem by umham35 on github for integrating ion into rails projects.